Suited change of basis coordinates for solving relativistic Lense-Thirring and frame dragging
I have not been able to find in textbook (Landau, Wald) the rationales driving to the  coordinate basis change proposed in MTW in order to comprehend the Lense Thirring / frame dragging effect in an spatial euclidian coordinate system.
My misunderstanding occurs in this context:
Considering a metric generated by a fluid having a non null angular momentum:
$$\mathbf{ds}^2=-\left(1-\frac{2M}{r}\right)\mathbf{d}t^2 -\left(4\epsilon_{jkl}S^k\frac{x^l}{r^3} \right)\mathbf{d}t\otimes\mathbf{d}x^j+\delta_{jk}\left(1+\frac{2M}{r}\right)\mathbf{d}x^j\otimes\mathbf{d}x^k$$
The body mass and intrinsic angular momentum of the fluid driving to this aforementioned metric are defined:
$$M=\int T^{00} d^3x$$
$$S_k=\int\epsilon_{klm}x^lT^{m0}d^3x$$
If we now consider a gyroscope evolving into this environment, we know that the gyroscope is precessing in this metric with an angular velocity of precession of:
$$
\mathbf{\Omega} = \frac{1}{r^3} \left[-\mathbf{S}+\frac{3\left(\mathbf{S}.\mathbf{x}\right)\mathbf{x}}{r^2}\right]
$$
Classicaly (I only found a very succint demonstration in MTW), to end-up with this results we need a specific coordinate transformation, a fixed  system of coordinate (pointing to far-away reference stars) bound to the center of mass of gyroscope. The specific one-forms tetrad required to achieve this above results are:
$$\boldsymbol{\omega}^\hat{t} = \left(1-\frac{2M}{r}\right)^{1/2}\mathbf{d}t+2\epsilon_{jkl} S^k \frac{x^l}{r^3} \mathbf{d}x^j$$
$$\boldsymbol{\omega}^\hat{j} = \left(1+\frac{2M}{r}\right)^{1/2} \mathbf{d}x^j$$
In the $\{\hat{t}, \hat{x}, \hat{y}, \hat{z}\}$ coordinate system the precession equation of the angular momentum of the gyroscope ($\mathbf{L}$) is written:
$$\frac{dL^\hat{i}}{d\hat{t}} = \epsilon_{\hat{j}\hat{k}\hat{l}}\Omega^{\hat{k}}L^{\hat{l}}$$
The "loop" is then closed by binding the $\epsilon_{\hat{j}\hat{k}\hat{l}}\Omega^{\hat{k}}L^{\hat{l}} = \Gamma_{\hat{i}\hat{j}\hat{0}}$  and change the basis once more from $\{\hat{t}, \hat{x}, \hat{y}, \hat{z}\}$ to $\{t, x, y, z\}$.  The $\Gamma_{\hat{i}\hat{j}\hat{0}}$ are derived from the metric tensor and contain the intrinsic angular momentum of the surrounding spatial fluid.
I would assume that the most opportune coordinate change to perform would be a coordinate change driving to a diagonal metric tensor and consider the precession in the Lorentz frame of the center of mass of the gyroscope.
Calculation of the transformation matrix and coordinate basis change applied to the metric tensor are not driving to any local Lorentzian metric.
I am missing a fundamental aspect of the physic beyond this specific change of coordinate system. Why this coordinate change?
In advance thank you for any help and clues.
